# Graph execution error in R's Keras when evaluating a model

Tags: r, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I currently try to build (and cross-validate) a Deep Neural Net in R using Keras. However, I always receive an error message when evaluating my model:

```
> Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) : 

>  InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error:

> Detected at node 'sequential_87/dense_351/Relu' defined at (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\Jan_p\AppData\Local\R-MINI~1\envs\R-RETI~1\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 64, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Users\Jan_p\AppData\Local\R-MINI~1\envs\R-RETI~1\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1716, in evaluate
      tmp_logs = self.test_function(iterator)
    File "C:\Users\Jan_p\AppData\Local\R-MINI~1\envs\R-RETI~1\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1525, in test_function
      return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "C:\Users\Jan_p\AppData\Local\R-MINI~1\envs\R-RETI~1\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1514, in step_function
      outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "C:\Users\Jan_p\AppData\Local\R-MINI~1\envs\R-RETI~1\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1507, in run_step
```

The traceback is

```
> 6: stop(structure(list(message = "ValueError: in user code:\n\n    File \"C:\\Users\\Jan_p\\AppData\\Local\\R-MINI~1\\envs\\R-RETI~1\\lib\\site-packages\\keras\\engine\\training.py\", line 1525, in test_function  *\n        return step_function(self, iterator)\n    File \"C:\\Users\\Jan_p\\AppData\\Local\\R-MINI~1\\envs\\R-RETI~1\\lib\\site-packages\\keras\\engine\\training.py\", line 1514, in step_function  **\n        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))\n    File \"C:\\Users\\Jan_p\\AppData\\Local\\R-MINI~1\\envs\\R-RETI~1\\lib\\site-packages\\keras\\engine\\training.py\", line 1507, in run_step  **\n        outputs = model.test_step(data)\n    File \"C:\\Users\\Jan_p\\AppData\\Local\\R-MINI~1\\envs\\R-RETI~1\\lib\\site-packages\\keras\\engine\\training.py\", line 1471, in test_step\n        y_pred = self(x, training=False)\n    File \"C:\\Users\\Jan_p\\AppData\\Local\\R-MINI~1\\envs\\R-RETI~1\\lib\\site-packages\\keras\\utils\\traceback_utils.py\", line 67, in error_handler\n        raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None\n    File \"C:\\Users\\Jan_p\\AppData\\Local\\R-MINI~1\\envs\\R-RETI~1\\lib\\site-packages\\keras\\engine\\input_spec.py\", line 264, in assert_input_compatibility\n        raise ValueError(f'Input {input_index} of layer \"{layer_name}\" is '\n\n    ValueError: Input 0 of layer \"sequential_106\" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 26), found shape=(None, 55)\n", 
       call = py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords), 
       cppstack = NULL), class = c("Rcpp::exception", "C++Error", 
   "error", "condition")))

> 5: py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords)

> 4: (structure(function (...) 
   {
       dots <- py_resolve_dots(list(...))
       result <- py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords)
       if (convert) 
           result <- py_to_r(result)
       if (is.null(result)) 
           invisible(result)
       else result
   }, class = c("python.builtin.method", "python.builtin.object"
   ), py_object = <environment>))(batch_size = 32L, verbose = 0L, 
       sample_weight = NULL, x = <environment>, y = <environment>, 
       callbacks = list())

> 3: do.call(object$evaluate, args)

> 2: evaluate.keras.engine.training.Model(adult.net, x = x.train[-fold, 
       ], y = as.matrix(y.train[-fold, ]), verbose = FALSE)

> 1: evaluate(adult.net, x = x.train[-fold, ], y = as.matrix(y.train[-fold, 
       ]), verbose = FALSE) at #65
```

I have not found any reference on the graph execution error. Worse, I train essentially the same model shortly before, without any complications. (the configuration is mostly identical, with the same network architecture, the same tuning parameters etc, but a different dataset.)
I have recipes, keras, tensorflow and reticulate installed on my machine

Running the command `for(x in reticulate::py_last_error()) cat(x, "\n")` gives me

```
> TypeError 
object of type 'Sequential' has no len() 
 
> TypeError: object of type 'Sequential' has no len()
```

Code:

```
    news.metric = "Accuracy"
    # Bit of data wrangling using recipes package
    news.keras.metric = ifelse(news.metric == "RMSE", "mse", "accuracy")
      
    news.neuralnet.recipe = recipe(OnlineNews[index.OnlineNews,],
                                    shares ~ .) %>%
      step_naomit(recipes::all_predictors(), recipes::all_outcomes()) %>%
      step_normalize(recipes::all_numeric_predictors()) %>%
      step_dummy(recipes::all_nominal_predictors(), 
                 -recipes::all_outcomes(), one_hot = FALSE) %>%
      step_nzv(all_predictors()) %>%
      prep(training = OnlineNews[index.OnlineNews,])
    news.train.neuralnet = news.neuralnet.recipe %>%
      bake(new_data = OnlineNews[index.OnlineNews,]) 
      
    x.train = news.train.neuralnet %>%
      subset(select = -shares) %>%
      data.matrix()
    y.train = matrix(ifelse(pull(news.train.neuralnet, shares) == "larger", 1, 0))
    
    # Define network architecture
    build_neuralnet = function(current.tunes){
      #print(current.tunes)
    
      neuralnet.architecture = keras_model_sequential() %>%
      # Fit general model
      
      # Network architecture
      layer_dense(units = current.tunes$nodes1,
                  activation = "relu",
                  input_shape = ncol(x.train)) %>%
      layer_batch_normalization() %>%
      layer_dropout(rate = current.tunes$dropout1) %>%
      layer_dense(units = current.tunes$nodes2, 
                  activation = "relu") %>%
      layer_batch_normalization() %>%
      layer_dropout(rate = current.tunes$dropout2) %>%
      layer_dense(units = current.tunes$nodes3,
                  activation = "relu") %>%
      layer_batch_normalization() %>%
      layer_dropout(rate = current.tunes$dropout3) %>%
      layer_dense(units = 1,
                  activation = current.tunes$activation) %>%
      
      # Backprogpagation
      compile(
        loss = "binary_crossentropy",
        optimizer = optimizer_sgd(),
        metrics = current.tunes$metrics
      )
      return(neuralnet.architecture)
    }
    
    
    # Later used to store accuracy metrics
    cv.frame = data.frame(row.number = integer(), fold.number = integer(), 
                          accuracy = integer())
    
    # Define tuning grid
    news.tuning.grid.keras = expand.grid(
      nodes1 = c(32, 64, 128), nodes2 = c(32, 64, 128, 256), nodes3 = c(64, 128, 256),
      dropout1 = c(0.1, 0.2, 0.4), dropout2 = c(0.1, 0.2, 0.4), 
      dropout3 = c(0.1, 0.2, 0.4),
      #optimizer = c(optimizer_adam(), optimizer_sgd()),
      learningrate = c(0.01, 0.05, 0.1),
      activation = ifelse(news.metric == "RMSE", "linear", "sigmoid"),
      metrics = news.keras.metric
    )
    
    # Large tuning grid, so use random model search
    tuning.to.try = sample.int(nrow(news.tuning.grid.keras),
                               nrow(news.tuning.grid.keras) / 50)
    
    # Let folds stay the same across tuning attempts
    folds.index = createFolds(y.train, k = 5, returnTrain = TRUE)
    
    for (i in tuning.to.try){ 
      # Pull current tuning values
      current.tunes = news.tuning.grid.keras[i,]
      news.net = build_neuralnet(current.tunes)
      # Now loop over folds, fit model, get accuracy
      fold.no = 0
      for (fold in folds.index){
        fold.no = fold.no + 1
        news.net.history = news.net %>%
          fit(
            x = x.train[fold,],
            y = as.matrix(y.train[fold,]),
            epochs = 35,
            batch_size = 128,
            validation_split = 0.2,
            callbacks = list(
              callback_early_stopping(patience = 5),
              callback_reduce_lr_on_plateau(factor = current.tunes$learningrate)
            ),
            verbose = FALSE
          )
        # Get prediction & accuracy
        
        model.mse = evaluate(adult.net, 
                                  x = x.train[-fold,], 
                                  y = as.matrix(y.train[-fold,]),
                                  verbose = FALSE)[["Accuracy"]]
        # dnn.prediction = predict(object = adult.net.fit1, x = x.train[-fold,])
        # model.accuracy = sum(dnn.prediction == y.train[-fold])
        # Save prediction & accuracy for further use
        cv.frame = cv.frame %>% rbind(data.frame(row.number = i, 
                                                 fold.number = fold.no,
                                                 mse = model.mse))
      }
    }
```

Edit: For some reason, some of the error message has been cut off, here the full message:

```
> Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) : 
  InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error:

> Detected at node 'sequential_114/dense_459/Relu' defined at (most recent call last):

> File "C:\Users\Jan_p\AppData\Local\R-MINI~1\envs\R-RETI~1\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 64, in error_handler
  return fn(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Jan_p\AppData\Local\R-MINI~1\envs\R-RETI~1\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1384, in fit
  tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
File "C:\R-packages\R\win-library\4.1\reticulate\python\rpytools\signals.py", line 46, in _signal_handler
  _callback(True)
File "C:\R-packages\R\win-library\4.1\reticulate\python\rpytools\call.py", line 13, in python_function
  res = rpycall.call_r_function(f, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Jan_p\AppData\Local\R-MINI~1\envs\R-RETI~1\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 64, in error_handler
  return fn(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Jan_p\AppData\Local\R-MINI~1\e
```

Comment: The error message is incomplete

Comment: Apologies, full error message now in the edit. Dunno why it cut off...